# Solve a nonlinear first order differential equation, can I use the method of solving Bernoulli equations?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this equation which I need to solve:

\begin{equation}
 v'(y) + 2\omega \tanh(\omega x) sech^2[\omega x]v^2 - 8\omega^3 \tanh(\omega x) [ 2 sech^2(\omega x) - \tanh^2(\omega x)]v = 0
\end{equation}

where $v$ is a function of $y$ and $\omega$ is an infinitesimally small parameter.

I was thinking, since $v$ is only a function of $y$ I could treat the other coefficients as constants, so label them $a$ and $b$.
This would change my equation to:

\begin{equation}
  v' + av^2-bv=0
\end{equation}

I then used the same method I would to solve a Bernoulli equation.
I introduce a variable $z = v^{-1}$

\begin{equation}
 z' + bz = a
\end{equation}

the integrating factor is $e^{by}$ I multiply both sides by the integrating factor and then integrate both sides with respect to $y$:

\begin{align}
e^{by}[\frac{dz}{dy} + bz] &= e^{by} \cdot a\\
\frac{d}{dy}[e^{by}\cdot z] &= a \cdot e^{by}\\
e^{by} \cdot z &= \frac{a \cdot e^{by} + cb}{b}\\
z &= \frac{a \cdot e^{by} + cb}{b \cdot e^{by}}\\
\end{align}

I now get:
\begin{equation}
 v = \frac{b \cdot e^{by}}{a \cdot e^{by} + cb}
\end{equation}

This is all part of a bigger solution where I am ultimately looking to find $u = sech^2(\omega x) \cdot v $ and then determine $\lim_{\omega ->0} u$

Can I use what I have for $v$ and sub my $a$ and $b$ back in to then continue with what I need for $u$?

Comment: If $v$ only depends on $y$, your approach is fine. However, I think you lost a term when you introduced $a$ and $b$

Comment: @Vasya I don't follow what you mean when you said I lost a term.  What term am I losing?  $v$ is definitely only a function of $y$.  However $u=(x,t)$ and $y=t$, neither of these come into play when solving for $v$ though.

Comment: @sarah_jamal: you have terms with $v^2$ and $v$ and it seems you lost $v$ term

Comment: @Vasya I see what you mean, sorry I thought you meant I would be losing a term in my solution.  Unfortunately this is not yielding my desired outcome. I end up with 0 when I calculate the limit.